# Changes in commit but not in source files

Tags: git, githooks

I have cloned git repository from another box. But when I have made changes, create commit locally and push them I do not see this changes in source files on source box. On this box I have pushed commit, but changes will be visible after `git reset --hard HEAD`.

I do not understand this behavior. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "fix" this intended behavior using one of [Git's server-side hooks (e.g. post-receive)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the "source" that checks out the HEAD (using `checkout`, no need to `reset`) to the working tree.